# Why is the number of digits I can enter the following form is limited?

Tags: qt, validation, qml, qt5

I have taken over the code from a former employee, that uses an input like this:

```
            TextField   {
                width: 0.5*parent.width
                height: 0.5*parent.height

                validator:  DoubleValidator {
                    notation: DoubleValidator.StandardNotation
                    decimals: 3
                    bottom: -99.99
                    top: 99.99
                }

                text: scanCom.x
                horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: TextInput.AlignVCenter

                onEditingFinished: {
                    scanCom.x = parseFloat(text)
                }
                onActiveFocusChanged:   {
                    if (!activeFocus && !acceptableInput)   {
                        xInvalidValueId.visible = true
                        text = scanCom.x
                    }
                }
            }
```

It does not allow entering non-digit numbers (which is nice) but also limits the available digits to 2 in total. I can enter 88, 8.8, or 0.88, but not 88.8. The validator seems to just check if the input is a double or not. How does it limit what I can type?

I grepped for Hints in the source with  `grep --color -Iins 'Hints' *.cpp *.h *.qml` and didn't find anything related to inputMethodHints.

Other TextFields in the same form accept arbitrary input.

Comment: Look at `decimals: 3` statement. Doesn't it limit the number of digits? Try to set it to 4, for example.

Comment: That field doesn't seem to have an effect. It was 1 when I took over. Stays the same even if I take it to 5.

Comment: What version of Qt / QtQuick are you using?

Comment: @Yoann Qt 5.10, QtQuick 2.17 QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Comment: Maybe it's due to `parseFloat(text)` method. Check its implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-doublevalidator.html#details):

> If notation is set to DoubleValidator.StandardNotation, and the input
>   contains more digits before the decimal point than a double in the
>   valid range may have, it is [...] rejected.

So you're near the expected behaviour. Anyway, I would use

```
notation: DoubleValidator.ScientificNotation
```

and see if arbitrary input is allowed.

Comment: Sorry but how come 88.8 is not between -99.99 and 99.99 and has more than 3 digits or not a double? I may be blind to something obvious.

Comment: Accepting because setting ScientificNotation made the problem go away, but I still don't understand why StandrdNotation behaves the way it does.